# Set Feature image in wordpress without upload

Tags: image, wordpress, amazon-s3

I have Images stored on s3 and calling from s3 in img tag. I can set feature image by inseting it to wp upload folder as in this thread

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post

Now the problem is, how to set feature image without uploading it to wp folder. It should call the image from s3 and set it as feature.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: why do you need to link a image or images stored in s3 to the featured image?

Comment: because I am creating an application that stores images to the amazon and don't want to save that image again to the upload folder.

Comment: I can add the image url by add_post_meta function, now I need to add _wp_attached_file with post_id. Any idea to do this?

Comment: Can't you simply adapt your theme to get the `post_meta`?

Comment: This is an application and will send data to wp without uploading images